# How can I get "Select All" working in my subclassed NSTextField/NSTextFieldCell?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstextfield, selectall, nstextfieldcell

Generally, when editing text in a text field/input/area/editor, pressing <kbd>⌘A</kbd> will select all of the current text in said field/input/area/editor. I've subclassed NSTextField and NSTextFieldCell, and no matter what I try, I can't seem to get basic "Select All" functionality working. I've tried implementing delegate protocols, intercepting events, manipulating commands made by selectors, and every other thing I can think of. What gives? (I can already hear the "Ever heard of Google?" refrains because of how simple this probably is, but I haven't found a single answer out there. I guess I can thank iOS for that.)

And before I forget to mention it, I also dragged a standard NSTextField into my nib to see if a non-subclassed NSTextField implements Select All behavior by default, and to my shock, it doesn't. Am I going crazy here, or am I completely overlooking something? Isn't Select All almost a requirement when implementing a text field? Apple's First Responder proxy handles everything under the sun (including two versions of selectAll (`selectAll` and `selectAll:`), but the n00b is strong with me, and I can't seem to make sense of any of this.

Any help/ideas would be immensely appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The application menu handles sending the keyboard shortcut actions to the application's current first responder. The missing connection would explain why your regular `NSTextField` objects are missing this functionality as well.

[image: Connection action in Interface Builder in Xcode 5]

Comment: Thanks for the response! I _have_ altered the default application menu, so I bet you're right. Why I would remove the Select All item is beyond me. Too many hours in front of this bright screen, I guess. I'll create a new Select All menu item, connect some actions, and report back. Thanks, Fruity.

Comment: I totally forgot to update this post. @FruityGeek nailed it. I had accidentally removed the "Select All" menu item from the application's MainMenu Nib. All's well that ends well. Cheers.